# how to create a new table based on the count from another table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Lets say that i have this table in mariadb:

Table1:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | Done | 01-08-2021 |
| Test2 | Done | 01-08-2021 |
| Test3 | Waiting | 02-08-2021 |
| Test4 | Done | 01-08-2021 |
| Test5 | Fail | 01-08-2021 |
| Test6 | Done with errors | 01-08-2021 |
| Test7 | Finished | 03-09-2021 |
| Test8 | Failed with many errors | 10-08-2021 |
| Test9 | Not tested yet | 10-10-2021 |

How can i make an sql query so i can have an output like this:

Table2

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Finished | 5 |
| Waiting to be finished | 2 |
| Failed | 2 |

So baically, what i want is to count the numbers of rows in Table1 which contain: Done, Done with errows or Finshed and to write that number in row **Finished** in Table2.
For the rows in Table1 that contain: Fail and Failed with many errors to be written to row **Failed** in Table2.
For the rows in Table1 that contain Waiting and Not tested yet to be written to row **Waiting to be finished** in Table2.

Comment: Why do you want this? You can fetch this information from the first table with a simple query. You should not store redundant data to you database. This will lead into many problems.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may aggregate using a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Col2 IN ('Done', 'Done with errors', 'Finished') THEN 'Finished'
         WHEN Col2 LIKE '%fail%' OR Col2 LIKE '%Fail%' THEN 'Failed'
         WHEN Col2 IN ('Waiting', 'Not tested yet') THEN 'Waiting to be finished'
    END AS Col1,
    COUNT(*) AS Col2
FROM Table1
GROUP BY 1;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT statuses.col1, COUNT(*)
FROM source_table
JOIN ( SELECT 'Finished' col1, 'Done' col2 UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Finished', 'Done with errors' UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Finished', 'Finished' UNION ALL 
       SELECT 'Failed', 'Fail' UNION ALL 
       SELECT 'Failed', 'Failed with many errors' UNION ALL 
       SELECT 'Waiting to be finished', 'Waiting' UNION ALL 
       SELECT 'Waiting to be finished', 'Not tested yet' ) statuses USING (col2)
GROUP BY statuses.col1;
```

The best way - create static table `statuses` with shown data and use it instead of dynamic subquery.

Comment: Thanks a lot @akina, also this one works